# How to display a notification prompt on button click? Windows Phone

Tags: c#, user-interface, windows-phone-8, toast, prompt

I'm trying to display a message to the user when they click a button but I'm not sure how to achieve this in Windows phone development.I know in Android you can use a `toast` but I can't find something similar for Windows phone, what I have found is this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662938(v=vs.105).aspx but its not the correct solution as it shows a notification at the title bar.

Does anyone have a simple solution to displaying a prompt to the user or something similar?

I'm looking for something similar to this:

[image: Sample user prompt]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MessageBox.Show("Success", "Location saved.", MessageBoxButton.OK);
```

You can use `MessageBox` to display simple information/prompts to the user in WP. More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ms598690(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: okay thanks and what controls the color of the message box? Can I add an extra parameter to set color?

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot set the color of the MessageBox. However, you can make it show a prompt and make the user choose an option, e.g.: OK or Cancel. A MessageBox is the simplest way to show info to the user though.

Comment: `Error No overload for method 'Show' takes 2 arguments ` is this the correct syntax?

Comment: @BrianJ -- looks like the answer forgot to include the 3rd parameter as shown in the documentation. You'll want to look at it to see the options.

Comment: @WiredPrairie Sorry about that and thanks for letting me know; I'll edit the answer right away :P

Comment: @BrianJ You can also make use of CustomMessageBox from WPToolkit or make your own prompt with Popup. AFAIK there is an option to choose a color.

Comment: @Romasz I will look into that option.

Answer (score 1):

[Windows phone toast notification](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-toast-prompt-in-depth). This may help you a lot. Download [Coding4Fun.Phone.Toolkit v1.2](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/new-coding4fun-phone-toolkit-v1-2-officially-released) from [here](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/new-coding4fun-phone-toolkit-v1-2-officially-released) and add reference in your solution.
Here is sample code how to display a custom notification(message) on button click may this will help you.

```
private void btnCustomizedToastPrompt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     SolidColorBrush gray = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);
     SolidColorBrush orange = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(200, 255, 117, 24));

    ToastPrompt toast = new ToastPrompt
    {
        Background = gray,
        Foreground = orange,
        Title = "Customized",
        Message = "Custom colors",
        FontSize = 30,
        TextOrientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Vertical,
        ImageSource =
            new BitmapImage(new Uri("ApplicationIcon.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
    };

    toast.Completed += toast_Completed;
    toast.Show();
}
```